# Where is LinkedIn pulling its page title and summary from?

Tags: html, linkedin-api

On my company's website I have the following page for our podcast episodes - https://ayehu.com/podcast/ .
Its HTML title tag is "Intelligent Automation Radio | Ayehu".

If I share this page via LinkedIn, it for some reason shows the title as "Podcast Archives | Ayehu" and provides a description of the page, whose text is nowhere to be found in the HTML source - see image. Any ideas where the title and text are being pulled from by LinkedIn?

[image]

Comment: This does not appear to be about programming, except perhaps by LinkedIn developers, which may or may not be on Stack Overflow. Seems like this would be better off asked on [LinkedIn's Help Forum](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum?trk=forum_driver)...

Comment: Ok, I'll ask there, thanks.